# I have a row chart ordered in descending order. I want to change the order to ascending. This is my code:

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, crossfilter

Vgrade is the row chart in descending order. Need to sort in ascending order. How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

```
vgrade
  .width(200)
  .height(200)
  .x(d3.scale.linear())
  .label(function(d) {
    return d.key + ":" + d.value.toFixed(0) + ""
  })
  .elasticX(true)
  .dimension(gradeD)
  .group(gradeG)
  .ordering(function(d) {
    return -d.value;
  });
```

Comment: add .ordering(function(d){ return d.value; });

Comment: @Dhaarani Thanku so much... it worked!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add .ordering(function(d){ return d.value; });